# QLineEdit : setValidator for 4bytes unsigned Integer not working

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget, qlineedit

I am using a `QTableWidget` to input values for a user-defined tool's parameters.  Each parameter has a maximum size limit in bytes.

I used `QIntValidator` with `QLineEdit` and `setCellWidget`.
It's working fine up to 4 bytes signed integers, while not taking entry when set for 4 bytes unsigned integer.

```
  QLineEdit *edit = new QLineEdit(ui->tableWidget);
  edit->setValidator(new QIntValidator(tpMinValue.at(i).toUInt(), tpMaxValue.at(i).toUInt(), edit));
  edit->setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { border: none }");
  ui->tableWidget->setCellWidget((i-1), 2, edit);
```

#### Examples

1. tool A: max size is 2 bytes (65,535) unsigned integer;
   I am able to enter values up to 65,535 in the cell.
2. tool B: max size is 4 bytes (2,147,483,647) signed integer;
   I am able to enter values up to 2,147,483,647 in the cell.
3. tool C: max size is 4 bytes (4,294,967,295) unsigned integer;
   I am **unable to enter any value** in the cell.

It is not allowing me to enter any number in the cell, since the max allowed value of QIntValidator is (2,147,483,647) signed integer.

Is there an alternative way to overcome the issue?

Answer (score 2):

This is because `QIntValidtor` works with `int` which is a *signed* integer. Someone else had a [similar problem with `QSpinbox`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26581444/qspinbox-with-unsigned-int-for-hex-input) and had to extend its functionality to work this out.

In other words, you're going to have to [implement your own validator class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvalidator.html#details).